# By iterating on the string, how can I extract more indexes and the corresponding values?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Given my string, I'm trying to extract only the numeric values, but with the index and find functions I can only extract the value 7.22.
How do I pick up the other three numeric values after the symbol "=" ?

```
stringa="[(Mark=7.22, Paola=3.12) , (Mark=30.1, Paola=1.78)]"
for i in stringa:
    i=stringa.index("=")
    n=stringa[i+1:i+5]
    print(n)
```

As output I get 7.22 printed the number of times as long as the string length! I, on the other hand, need you to print out 7.22, 3.12, 30.1 and 1.78.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

print(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", "[(Mark=7.22, Paola=3.12) , (Mark=30.1, Paola=1.78)]"))
```

Output:

```
['7.22', '3.12', '30.1', '1.78']
```

If you need to convert to float

```
print(list(map(float, re.findall("\d+\.\d+", "[(Mark=7.22, Paola=3.12) , (Mark=30.1, Paola=1.78)]"))))
```

Output:

```
[7.22, 3.12, 30.1, 1.78]
```

If you want to save the result to a variable

```
x = list(map(float, re.findall("\d+\.\d+", "[(Mark=7.22, Paola=3.12) , (Mark=30.1, Paola=1.78)]")))
```

Comment: thank you very much the program works, but if I wanted to save this vector within a variable x (for example) how should I do it? thanks again for the help!!!

Comment: @luna8899 updated my answer. Accept the answer if it has solved your problem

Comment: Excuse me, my question is this: once I get the vector x with the numbers how do I extract only the first two values? For example [7.22, 3.12]

Comment: @luna8899 the resulting value is a list, so in order to get the first 2 elements - `first_element = lst[0]; second_element = lst[1]`

Comment: Ah ok excuse me, what if I want to take more values and put them inside a vector?

Comment: You can use list slicing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: I apologize again, I promise this is the last question, but once I have the vector x,y=[7.22, 3.12, 30.1, 1.78]. How can I automatically and simultaneously take the first two values each time and put them inside an operation?

Comment: @luna8899 `first_two_values = lst[:2]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219334/discussion-between-luna8899-and-bigbounty).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still have a problem on the program, I have to take individually, within a for cycle, the values of the list so that then at each cycle I put this value within a function, how should I do it?

list=[7.22, 3.12, 30.1, 1.78]
for i in list:
take the first value
Put this value in function z